# Shooting Corporate Brass, am I forgetting anything

Tags: equipment-recommendation, technique

Getting ready to do a series of head & shoulder shots for some corporate brass. Should be simple, though I don't want to forget anything basic.

Equipment list:

- Nikon D700
- 50mm 1.4
- 80-200mm 2.8 (I do have a nice long room to work with)
- CF cards
- SB-800
- (2) SB-600's
- 24" softbox
- 15" soft box
- 3 light stands
- backdrop stand and cross bar
- 7 backdrops
- positioning stool
- UV corrective gels
- batteries
- lens cleaner
- water and granola bars
- shooting schedule with names and room for additional contact info
- pen

I think that covers it. Planning on a simple 3 light set up: key, fill and rim (or splash). What am I forgetting?

Comment: If you want to be hardcore you could bring a laptop/computer and monitor for tethered shooting for the people to see their pictures :)

Comment: was thinking about that, though I've never done it before. D700 and MacBookPro. Any hints?

Comment: Yea, I use my MacBook Pro as well with Lightroom (2 or 3).  In LR2 you shoot pictures to a folder and ask LR to monitor that folder (file -> auto import).  In LR3 you can do 'tethered capture' directly (file -> tethered capture).  If you don't own either you can download a free 30 day trial.

Comment: You can also do tethered capturing in Aperture, if you have that. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4176

Comment: If I recall Nikon Capture does something like that, though the software is kind of clunky.

Comment: Add to List: gum, combs, fabric softener sheets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing:

- Backup camera. You absolutely need backup camera, and backup flashes if you can swing it.
- Immediate backup of images. You don't need to go hardcore here, a laptop will work, but you don't want to reshoot if your cards crap out.
- Contract/Release paperwork. Make sure the terms of the shoot are laid out, and that you have secured the release to use any photograph as part of your own portfolio/advertising.

Comment: Paperwork/release is done. Took care of that with the last photo-shoot I did for them. Good idea on the backup camera though. Will bring laptop and card reader. Thx.

Answer (score 7):

How about an assistant / volunteer to test the lighting setups on before the big guns arrive so you're not faffing around?

Oh and gaffa tape for the lightstands and any cabling. Always bring tape to shoots.... and everywhere else you go in life.

Comment: Got the tape...and the knife...and the flashlight. No assistant though. Thought about Jrista as he's in town, but not sure how to get a hold of him. Does he answer to a bat symbol?

Comment: In that case good luck!